# How to use events as a function in React FullCalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I currently need to dynamically load events in my database, however after numerous attempts, I still have not gotten it to work with React FullCalendar. Has anyone successfully gotten this to work?

In this method, I am successfully able to get the events to load in the calendar, however, my API is being continuously being called. This led me to think it was because I do not have an arrow function in events

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState(0);
const getEvents = async () => {
    //Get events from database
    const theEvents = await ...
    setEvents(theEvents);
};

const returnEvent = () => {
    getEvents();
    return events;
}

<FullCalendar
    timeZone={'Europe/London'}
    now={DateTime.local().setZone('Europe/London').toISO()}
    ref={calendarRef}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    height='100%'
    ...
    events = {returnEvent()}
/>
```

However, if I do

```
<FullCalendar
    timeZone={'Europe/London'}
    now={DateTime.local().setZone('Europe/London').toISO()}
    ref={calendarRef}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    height='100%'
    ...
    events = {() => returnEvent()}
/>
```

My API gets called continuously called and none of the events load on the calendar. I think if you do arrow functions on events, none of the events will load as when I do something like this, it does not even work.

```
const returnEvent = () => {
    let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, '') // YYYY-MM-DD of today
    const events = [
      {
        id: createEventId(),
        title: 'All-day event',
        start: todayStr
      },
      {
        id: createEventId(),
        title: 'Timed event',
        start: todayStr + 'T12:00:00'
      }
    ]
    // getEvents();
    return events;
}

<FullCalendar
    timeZone={'Europe/London'}
    now={DateTime.local().setZone('Europe/London').toISO()}
    ref={calendarRef}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    height='100%'
    ...
    events = {() => returnEvent()}
/>
```

However, if I change `events = {returnEvent()}` it does work. Can someone please send an example or guide me on how to call events as a function in React FullCalendar?

Comment: I'd expect it ought to be `events = {returnEvent}`? You're supposed to provide a reference to the function so that fullcalendar can call it whenever it needs to. If you put in the () then you're providing the result of executing the function once. That's the principle. I'm not providing as an outright answer because I don't use react so I don't know if that's the exact syntax to achieve it.

Comment: @ADyson That does not work, as no events are shown on the calendar, and also causes an infinite loop. You would want to have `() => returnEvent` so an infinite render does not happen. Either I'm doing something wrong or there is an issue with the React version of fullCalendar. I also created a different file where I have a `<button onClick = {() => returnEvent()}>` and this does not cause of an infinite loop, leading me to think there is an issue with React FullCalendar.

Comment: Hm. Again I'm not a react expert, but according to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react in the "callbacks" section, there's an example of how to specify a callback into the fullCalendar options. The example there is for dateClick, but the principle is the same - you're supplying a function reference for fullCalendar to execute at the appropriate time. So if you make your version in the same style as the example I'd expect it to work.

Comment: But currently neither your `getEvents` or `returnEvent` functions follow the pattern described in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function - they don't fetch events and then supply them to fullcalendar via the provided callback. So you need to implement that correctly before you can expect any real success.

Comment: However if, after that, you do believe you've found an issue with fullCalendar, please follow the process to raise a bug with the fullCalendar project, as described at https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . At stackoverflow we can help with your implementation of fullCalendar into your application, but we can't help with internal bugs in the software.

Comment: @ADyson I appreciate you for trying to help me. They are using React Components while I am using React Hooks. Essentially I am doing the same thing as they are in the examples, however, in React hooks. Regarding `getEvents` and `returnEvent`, I am fetching events through `getEvents` and then returning the events in `returnEvent`, so shouldn't it work? I was able to show the events on the calendar with `events = {returnEvent()}`, however it just made the loop call infinitely. Thus, I want events = {() => returnEvent()} to work, except it does not.

Comment: @ADyson I am still new to the library so I might be making mistakes, however, I feel like someone has definitely gotten this to work. If I can’t get this to work, I might have to just do `events = {events}` and `datesSet = {() => function()}` to get events dynamically, which may or may not be ideal.

Comment: `I am fetching events through getEvents and then returning the events in returnEvent, so shouldn't it work`...no. Look at the example in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. fullcalendar supplies 3 arguments to the callback. One of them is "successCallback". This is a function reference. The callback you implement needs to call this function, and pass into it the list of events you've downloaded from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with the same problem this is how I go it to work.

I had to place the events I received from my api call into the successcallback.

```
  <FullCalendar
         displayEventEnd
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        headerToolbar={{
          left: "prev,next",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
        }}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
        events={(info, successCallback) => getEvents(info, successCallback)}
      />
```

---

```
 const getEvents = (info : any, successCallback: any) =>{
     getAcademicCalendarEvents(info.startStr, info.endStr).then((events) =>{
      successCallback(events)
      })
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the line to `events = {returnEvent()}`, events is being assigned to the returned value of calling `returnEvent()`.

You do not need to return anything from `returnEvent()` because `events` is available in your application state. If you want to pass the `events` state to `<FullCalendar>`, you can simply pass it the prop `events = {events}`.

```
<FullCalendar
    timeZone={'Europe/London'}
    now={DateTime.local().setZone('Europe/London').toISO()}
    ref={calendarRef}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    height='100%'
    ...
    events={events}
/>
```

Obviously, events is not going to hold anything meaningful when the application first renders as it is being initialized as `0`.

If you'd like to have events be initialized as the response from your API call, you can return it in the `useState` callback function:

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState(() => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/events');
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
})
```

Comment: Hi, if I do this I can not change my events dynamically. I am trying to implement this, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function as this leads it so events are loaded dynamically. For example, when you change the month via FullCalendar, it will automatically call and load the dates for the next month through `events = {() => returnEvent()}`. The example I have above does not have the parameters yet as I am still trying to get the basic example to work.